# Lombok doesnt create constructors

Tags: java, maven, lombok

**Solution by @AdilOoze**

> If you are using IntelliJ please turn on annotation processing in the
>   settings

**Question**

Everything worked fine yesterday. Today I added the gson dependency and it doesn't work anymore :(

Everything works when I create constructors manually

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
    list.add(new Person("AA","xx", 18));
    list.add(new Person("BB", "yy", 21));
    list.add(new Person("CC", "zz", 36));

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);

    System.out.println(json);
}
```

Person.class with `@AllArgsConstructor` and `@RequiredArgsConstructor`

```
public class Person {
    @NonNull private String name;
    private String lastname;
    @NonNull private int age;
}
```

Unless I did something wrong in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: "it doesn't work anymore", that's a pretty vague description. can you be more specific?

Comment: share the stack trace / build error message.

Comment: If you are using IntelliJ please turn on annotation processing in the settings

Comment: @AdilOoze thanks a lot! Now it works and Im going to read more about it

Comment: @RafalK You can also answer your own questions. I added a community answer with the comment from AdilOoze

Comment: @RafalK, I have posted my comment as the answer - please accept and upvote this as the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using IntelliJ please **turn on annotation processing** in the settings.

*Note: you may also need to have IntelliJ Lombok plugin installed*